# Vue.js transitions with SCSS loops not working

Tags: vue.js, sass

I am importing a SCSS file into my App.vue component. I am using SCSS loops to create multiple CSS classes and then using Vue transitions to animate elements.  Take the following component:

`Home.vue`

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <transition name="fade-direction-100" enter-active-class="fade-up-1000-enter-active">
      <h1 v-if="show">Hello World</h1>
    </transition>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'home',
  data() {
    return {
      show: false
    };
  },
  mounted: function() {
    this.show = true;
  }
};
</script>
```

This works as expected and the H1 element animates opacity and translateX. However the transition does not animate if I put all classes inside the same loop:

```css
// This works

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-enter-active,
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-leave-active {
    transition-duration: #{$i * 100}ms;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }
}

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-enter,
  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(#{$i * 100}px);
  }
}

// But this fails

@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-enter-active,
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-leave-active {
    transition-duration: #{$i * 100}ms;
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0);
    transition-property: all;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
  }

  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-enter,
  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(#{$i * 100}px);
  }
}
```

I cannot figure out why the separate loops work but creating multiple classes in the same loop would fail. In both cases, the same CSS is being compiled. Why would the two separate loops work but putting everyone in one loop fail?

Link to repo: [Repository](https://github.com/joelhoelting/who_said_it_v2_frontend/tree/develop)

Edit:

The following SCSS works as intended:

```css
@for $i from 1 through 10 {
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-enter-active,
  .fade-up-#{$i * 100}-leave-active {
    transition: all #{$i * 100}ms ease;
  }

  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-enter,
  .fade-direction-#{$i * 100}-leave-to {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(#{$i * 100}px);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What changes is the order of rules in the resulting CSS.

For example, your first snippet creates all the *up* rules, then all the *direction* rules

```css
.fade-up-100... { ... }
.fade-up-200... { ... }
.fade-up-...

.fade-direction-100... { ... }
.fade-direction-200... { ... }
.fade-direction...
```

Your second snippet creates alternating *up* and *direction* rules

```css
.fade-up-100... { ... }
.fade-direction-100... { ... }
.fade-up-200... { ... }
.fade-direction-200... { ... }
```

What you're seeing is CSS's [*cascading order*](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#cascading-order) at play. In your first snippet, 
`fade-direction-100-enter` will come after `fade-up-1000-enter-active` and its conflicting rules (namely `opacity`) will win.

In the second snippet, `fade-up-1000-enter-active` appears much later than `fade-direction-100-enter`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm terrible with transition classes and have to read the documentation a hundred times every time I approach the subject but in general, it seems you should not specify any concrete states (eg `opacity`) within your `-active` classes. Those classes are where you define the behaviour, eg `transition`.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. Same, the documentation hasn't yet clicked for me. The base class has `opacity: 0` but shouldn't the active class have `opacity: 1`?

Comment: @JoelHoelting no, the `-active` class applies for the entire duration of the transition, including the start and end states so if you put `opacity` there and in `-enter`, they will conflict. The diagram here does a reasonable job of explaining it ~ https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transition-Classes

Comment: Ah, I see what you are talking about. I just don't understand how if the enter class has `opacity: 0` and `transform: translateY(100px)` the active class will be `opacity: 1` and `transform: translateY(0)` without explicitly stating so.

Comment: The `enter` class only lasts for one frame (we're talking micro-seconds) then it is removed. So if your `active` class says to transition opacity, `enter` comes along and sets it invisible, then `enter` is removed so it reverts to default `opacity` for that element but because `active` is still there, the transition is in place. Once the transition completes, all the extra classes are removed so you're left with the default styles